# Name of certain combinatorial numbers?

Tags: co.combinatorics, terminology

Do the numbers of the form
$A_k(n)=(-1)^{k+1}\frac{n}{k}\binom{n-k-1}{k-1}$
have a particular name?

Comment: What are the conditions on $k$ ? Without condition, you have not an integer sequence.

Comment: To know how you cama across this sequence might help in answering. 

Comment: A general bit of advice for answering questions of this kind: calculate the first several values, and enter them into the box here: http://oeis.org/ 

Answer (score 5):

These numbers are sequence [A029635](http://oeis.org/A029635) in the OEIS, where they are called the $(1,2)$-Pascal triangle (or Lucas triangle). More precisely, the numbers given there are
$T(n,k) = \frac{n+k}{n}\binom nk$, so $A_k(n) = (-1)^{k+1}T(n-k,k)$. They are all integers.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the minus signs aside, the OP's formula for $A_k(n)$ appears as is in the OEIS entry http://oeis.org/A157000 which gives a reference to page 199 of Riordan's *Introduction to Combinatorial Analysis*, which refers to a 1943 paper by Kaplansky, "Solution of the 'Probléme des Ménages'," in the *Bulletin of the AMS* (vol. 49, pp. 784-785).  The Wikipedia entry http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menage_problem may be helpful in tracking things down.  I don't see an explicit name given to these numbers.